# Change image in custom UIImageView Class

Tags: xcode, uiimageview, subclass

I want to change the picture of my custom UIImageView Subclass by a timer. But it doesn't work. Can you help me?

This is my code:

```
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {

    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        [self update];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)update {

    self.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Green.png"];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5 target:self selector:@selector(change) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}

-(void)change {

    self.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Red.png"];

}
```

Thanks!